# Capture UIView as UIImage

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, uiimageview, uiimage

I have been using this method to convert a `UIView` into `UIImage`. i.e. screen snapshot of a view -

```
@interface UIView(Extended) 

- (UIImage *) imageByRenderingView;

@end


@implementation UIView(Extended)


- (UIImage *)imageByRenderingView
{   
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.bounds.size);
    [self.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *resultingImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return resultingImage;
}

@end
```

To use it, I do this -

`UIImage *currImage = [self.view imageByRenderingView];`

This gives the image representation of the entire `UIView`. Now I want 2 images, one is of the top half of the `UIView` and the other is the bottom half. How do I do that?

Comment: Note that (from my experience) `renderInContext:` can be pretty expensive. I'm doing it in a `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` (not having, right now, another option) and this obviously means lagging.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can split your `UIImage` in two by using this code:

```
CGImageRef topOfImageCG =
         CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(currImage.CGImage,
                                      CGRectMake(0,
                                                 0,
                                                 currImage.size.width,
                                                 currImage.size.height / 2.0));

UIImage *topOfImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:topOfImageCG];

CGImageRelease(topOfImageCG);
```

Comment: but this selector takes - `CGImageRef CGImageCreateWithImageInRect ( CGImageRef image, CGRect rect );`. How to convert `UIImage` which I have to `CGImageRef` ?

Comment: Git It ! image.CGImage where image is a UIImage object :)

Comment: Excellent. Just what I was looking for :)